# find shift time between two time in sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have ShiftMaster table where each machine is allocate start time and  end time, machine can be multiple shift. there some jobe is process on machine.

i.e ShiftMaster  e.g as

```
MachineID   SHIFTID     STIME           ETIME
A110T02     1       07:00:00.0000000    16:00:00.0000000
A110T02     2       14:00:00.0000000    23:00:00.0000000
A110T02     3       23:00:00.0000000    07:00:00.0000000
```

if i pass machine Name , start Job date time  and End Job time  it should retune shift start time  and End time.

i am facing problem with third shift because it involve mid night time i.e two days

i am expecting  if provide input like this

```
@machineName = 'A110T02'

@startJobdatetime = '2015-12-01 23:02:00'

@EndJobdatetime = '2015-12-01 23:20:00'
```

result should  return

3        23:00:00.0000000    07:00:00.0000000

or
proper format is given in this link [enter link description here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e0a32f50-ad53-4055-9a3d-b7db0fe58dd9/find-shift-time-between-two-time?forum=transactsql)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
declare @machineName varchar(50) = 'A110T02'
declare @startJobdatetime datetime = '2015-12-01 23:02:00'
declare @EndJobdatetime datetime = '2015-12-01 23:20:00'

SELECT *
FROM @ShiftMaster
WHERE MachineID = @machineName
    AND CAST(DATEADD(hour, -7, @startJobdatetime) as time) >= DATEADD(hour, -7, STIME)
    AND CAST(DATEADD(hour, -7, @EndJobdatetime) as time) <= DATEADD(NANOSECOND, -100, DATEADD(hour, -7, ETIME))
```

- You have to test it and make sure there is no rounding errors around 23:59:59.999.
- If basically shift everything by 7hours since the shift start at 7AM.

**Output:**

```
MachineID   SHIFTID STIME               ETIME
A110T02     3       23:00:00.0000000    07:00:00.0000000
```

**Data:**

```
declare @ShiftMaster table(MachineID varchar(50), SHIFTID int , STIME time, ETIME time)
INSERT INTO @ShiftMaster(MachineID, SHIFTID, STIME, ETIME) values
    ('A110T02', 1, '07:00:00.0000000', '16:00:00.0000000')
    , ('A110T02', 2, '14:00:00.0000000', '23:00:00.0000000')
    , ('A110T02', 3, '23:00:00.0000000', '07:00:00.0000000')
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 DECLARE @Tmp table (MachineID VARCHAR(20),SHIFTID INT,STIME VARCHAR(25),ETIME VARCHAR(25)) 
INSERT @Tmp SELECT 'A110T02',1,'07:00:00.0000000','16:00:00.0000000'
INSERT @Tmp SELECT 'A110T02',2,'14:00:00.0000000','23:00:00.0000000'
INSERT @Tmp SELECT 'A110T02',3,'23:00:00.0000000','07:00:00.0000000'

DECLARE @machineName VARCHAR(20) = 'A110T02'
 ,@startJobdatetime VARCHAR(25) = '2015-12-01 23:02:00' 
 ,@EndJobdatetime VARCHAR(25) = '2015-12-01 23:20:00'
 ,@ShiftId INT = 3

    ;with t11 as 
 (select MachineID,SHIFTID,
 cast(CAST(left(@startJobdatetime,10) AS datetime)+cast(stime as time) as datetime) as st,
 cast(cast(left(@startJobdatetime,10) AS datetime)+cast(ETIME as time) as datetime) et 
 from @tmp where cast(etime as time)>cast(stime as time)
  union all
  select MachineID,SHIFTID,
  cast(CAST(left(@startJobdatetime,10) AS datetime)+cast(stime as time) as datetime),
  cast(CAST(left(@startJobdatetime,10) AS datetime)+cast('23:59:59.999' as time) as datetime) 
  from @Tmp where cast(etime as time)<cast(stime as time)
  union all
 select MachineID,SHIFTID,
 CAST(left(@startJobdatetime,10) AS datetime),
 cast(cast(left(@startJobdatetime,10) as datetime)+cast(ETIME as time) as datetime) from @Tmp 
 where cast(etime as time)<cast(stime as time)
 ) 
 select t.MachineID,t.SHIFTID,t.STIME,t.ETIME from t11  join @Tmp t on t.MachineID=t11.MachineID  and t.SHIFTID=t11.SHIFTID
 where t11.MachineID = @machineName  and st<=cast(@startJobdatetime as datetime) and et>=cast(@EndJobdatetime as datetime)
```

Comment: if i give input  DECLARE @machineName VARCHAR(20) = 'A110T02'
 ,@startJobdatetime VARCHAR(25) = '2015-12-01 00:06:00' 
 ,@EndJobdatetime VARCHAR(25) = '2015-12-01 06:33:00' , it returning null

Comment: i have modified it to include your query, your logic of shift recoding is not clear,  thank you